# Upgrading to OS X Mavericks (10.9) via Screen Sharing

Tags: macos, upgrade, remote-desktop

When I upgrade to OS X Mavericks (10.9), after the final reboot (where it asks for your Apple ID), should I expect Screen Sharing to be functioning properly? (Q: Has anyone done this, or can verify that they've seen or heard it work?)

I'm running a Mac mini (Late-2012) using Screen Sharing with no physical display attached.

Notes

1. I have already installed ARD 3.7.1 - http://support.apple.com/kb/HT6045

   - and it is working fine
   - so I no longer have the firewall issue as mentioned here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5520097

     - (with 10.8.5 and ARD 3.7, I had to disable the firewall in order to use Screen Sharing)

---

**Update**

**The upgrade when smoothly**.  (I also had SSH (Remote Login) enabled just in case).  I thought the upgrade might take 45 minutes; when it took longer I felt a little concerned, but right at about the 1 hour mark, I saw the Mac mini's (Internet Sharing) wifi signal on again (yay!), and Screen Sharing working just like normal! :)  It showed the progress bar for the final installation step, just before the "Sign in with your Apple ID" screen.

(As long as you don't run into any installation problems), after the initial Screen Sharing disconnect by the installation process starting, it's completely unattended and easy/painless, took an hour.  All the sharing services seemed to work normally after the installation process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm reasonably sure that I updated my iMac from 10.8 to 10.9 without having to re-enable any of those features. I wasn't using the ARD client (or server), just the built-in "Screen Sharing" VNC service, and the upgrade itself was done in-person.

If I were you I'd just make sure SSH is definitely enabled, so if you -do- have to re-enable VNC after updating, you can do so from the command line. Chances are, though, you'll be able to re-connect VNC/ARD immediately after reboot.

Also, OS X updates nowadays tend to reboot right back into a user session so the installation can finish -- I don't believe you'll get trapped outside of a user session.

Answer (score 2):

I did this with absolutely no problems.

If you have Screen Sharing turned on in the Mac Mini then connect to it from another Mac (I used a MacBook Air) and save the password into the keychain on the 2nd Mac. You don't need ARD, normal screen sharing will do the job.

Now run the 10.9 installer. At the reboot you will lose your connection but just reconnect and you can watch parts of the install process. Then right at the end there is a final reboot and the Mac Mini is ready for you to reconnect again and go to work.

It's painless though I do admit to making sure I also had ssh set up and running before I did it "just in case".